# Why SwiftUI Table doesn‘t track changes in @Observable object?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-table

I try to build Table with Observation framework but Table doesn't track changes in data. However, the List keeps track.

```
@Observable
final class Item: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var value: Int
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.value = value
    }
}

@Observable
final class AppModel {
    
    var items: [Item]
    
    init() {
        var items: [Item] = []
        for i in 0...10 {
            items.append(Item(value: i))
        }
        self.items = items
    }
    
    func updateValue() {
        let index = Int.random(in: 0..<items.count)
        items[index].value = Int.random(in: 200...300)
    }
    
    func startTimer() {
        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.updateValue()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    
    @State private var appModel = AppModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(appModel)
        }
    }
}  

  struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(AppModel.self) private var appModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Table(appModel.items) {
                TableColumn("Value") {
                    Text("\($0.value)")
                }
            }
            List(appModel.items) {
                Text("\($0.value)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minHeight: 640)
        .onAppear {
            appModel.startTimer()
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: `Item` is supposed to be a struct, just `struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var value: Int
}`

Comment: @vadian, thank you! This works. Can you write this comment in answer and explain why Item must be the struct?

Comment: I think Apple just forgot to implement this for `Table`.